Hp enclosure c7000 OA swap after failure
one of two OAs has died, yesterday i replaced it, but it was not new it was used, now i am not sure if it is synched with active one. Is there some way to check?
I was reading docs and cli commands and i saw its only possible to show active config, not standby. I set up all network information on it, but i dont see anything in logs about sync, also there is no manuall sync command.
Also i tried to hard reset the standby OA, but it appears that only active can be hard restored and im not sure if standby has the correct config.
